# Calculate property at call time without using function invocation syntax

Tags: javascript

is there any pattern I can use to compute a variable at call time (like a property in C#)

```
var A = (function() {
    var self = {};
    var a = 0;
    self.x = function (){
        a = a+1;
        return a;
    };
    return self;
});
```

Normally, the call would be:

```
var bla = A.x();
```

but I would like to evaluate it and get its value as a property:

```
var bla = A.x;
console.log(bla); // prints "1"
```

I don't want the () operator, but I still want to compute/calculate the property value when I access `A.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be talking about getters and setters.
Those are function that gets called 'behind the scene' when you read (get) or assign (set) an object property.
They are quite standard (IE>=9), but have a somehow complicated syntax.
Look mdn  :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/defineProperty

A (verbose) example, implementing a property backed by a variable :

```
var A = (function() {
   var self = {};
   var x = 0;
   var xPropertyDescriptor = { enumerable : true ,
                               get : function() { return x },
                               set : function(val) { x=val }   };
   Object.defineProperty(self, 'x', xPropertyDescriptor);
   return self;
} () );
```

After the call to defineProperty, you can access 'x' just like a regular property, and either the get or set function will get called.
So basically, writing :

```
A.x = 12 // will call the getter : function(12) { x=12 }, and set the variable.
```

Notice that you can define a getter/setter on the prototype for later having more efficient object creation (otherwise you have to define them in the constructor for each instance.).
Yet defining the properties in the constructor is the only way to use a closure (like in the example above) to have truly private members.

In use :

```
var res = A.x ;  // res == 0
A.x = 12 ;
var res2 = A.x   //  res2==12
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
var bla = A.x;
console.log(bla());
//or
console.log(bla.call());
```

There are a couple more options, but these are the most straightforward ones.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ecmascript5, there's a `defineProperty` method you can use to define getters and setters for properties.

Take a look on this: http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html

So, as detailed in the example linked, you can define a getter/setter like this:

```
var myTest = {
    val : "Initial Value",
    get value () {
        return this.val + " Modified";
    },
    set value(newVal) {
        this.val = newVal;
    }
};

myTest.value // "Initial Value Modified"
myTest.value = "foo"
myTest.value // "foo Modified"
```

Good luck.

PS: You should keep in mind the compatibility issues this may bring. Please read the link, you'll find detailed info there.